# Is it possible to reset Google Analytics for Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I figured out how to let Firebase ignore my device from collecting Analytics data, because it distort it a lot. But how is it possible to reset the analytics?

Answer (score 6):

While you cannot reset data for the entire project, as of more recent SDK versions, GDPR functionality has provided a way to delete data for a specific device. So while you should still use a staging project separate from your prod data, if you do end up needing to delete test device data, this can be done with [this process](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9019185).

Call `resetAnalyticsData` to remove Analytics client data and reset the app id. Use the [User Deletion API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/userdeletion/v3/) to remove data from the Analytics servers for a specific device.

Answer (score 1):

You can request data deletion on specific event and parameters on Google Analytics.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9940393?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no such way where you can 'RESET' Firebase Analytics. I think that applies to Google Analytics as well.

Like you mentioned you can filter your device but then you can't set it to zero. A workaround would be to adding new events and filters, having custom comparison et al.